# Change the comparator for a map that is defined by a variadic template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following piece of code,

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct alpha{
    alpha() = default;
    alpha(std::string str, int i ) : mystr(str), num(i){}
    std::string mystr{"abc"};
    int num{0};
    bool operator <( const alpha &al ) const
    {
       return ( mystr < al.mystr );
    }
};
struct beta{
    beta() = default;
    beta(std::string str, int i ) : mystr(str), num(i){}
    std::string mystr{"abc"};
    int num{0};
    bool operator <( const beta &b1 ) const
    {
       return ( mystr < b1.mystr );
    }

};

template<template<typename ...> class Tcont, typename... Titem>
struct label_str
{
    Tcont<Titem...> kindA;
};

struct Label_map
{
    label_str<std::map, alpha, beta> al_beta_map;
};

struct big_map
{
    Label_map first;
    Label_map second;
};

int main()
{
    auto a1 = alpha("a1", 1);
    auto a2 = alpha("a2", 2);
    auto a3 = alpha("a3", 3);
    auto a4 = alpha("a4", 4);
    auto a5 = alpha("a5", 5);

    auto b1 = beta("b1", 1);
    auto b2 = beta("b2", 2);
    auto b3 = beta("b3", 3);
    auto b4 = beta("b4", 4);
    auto b5 = beta("b5", 5);

    big_map bigg;

    auto &first_map = bigg.first;
    auto &second_map = bigg.second;

    first_map.al_beta_map.kindA[a5] =  b5;
    first_map.al_beta_map.kindA[a2] =  b2;
    first_map.al_beta_map.kindA[a3] =  b3;
    first_map.al_beta_map.kindA[a4] =  b4;
    first_map.al_beta_map.kindA[a1] =  b1;
    auto &mmmap = first_map.al_beta_map.kindA;
    for ( auto [p,_] : mmmap ) 
        std::cout << "( " << p.mystr << ", " << p.num << " )" << std::endl;
}
```

I want to change the comaparator for alpha and beta to `num` instead of `mystr`.  I understand that I have to write a custom lambda to compare but I am not sure because of the variadic templates. Assuming I do not have access to change the alpha and beta, how do I do this?

godbolt like is here [Link](https://godbolt.org/z/8sv7dojaK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of the custom comparator must be passed to `std::map` as the third argument, you can actually use the variadic `label_str` to your advantage there:

```
struct num_comparator {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T &l, const T &r) const {
        return (l.num < r.num);
    }
};
struct Label_map {
    label_str<std::map, alpha, beta, num_comparator> al_beta_map;
};
```

One could use a lambda but the hassle with it is the lambdas are not default constructible until C++20, meaning just `std::map<alpha, beta,decltype(global_lambda)>` is not enough, you have to explicitly pass it in the ctor too. That could be done in your case but I see `struct` simpler.

Just note that `std::map` only ever compares it's keys, `alpha`s in your case. `beta::operator<` is never used.

Comment: Thanks! I was planning on having betas as keys too at some point of time.

Comment: @Morpheus In that case, `num_comparator` will work for them too :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. How did you know that the map's this argument accepts a struct? and how did the whole thing being variadic actually help us?

Comment: @Morpheus 1) Because that is [how `std::map` type is defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). It accepts a type which must satisfy "Compare requirements", see the link. 2) Because it allowed us to easily pass it through `label_str` to actual map's definition. I said "advantage" because I did not have to change `label_str`'s definition to accommodate the third template argument.